# Noe4j : There is not enough memory to perform the current task

Tags: performance, memory, neo4j

When we query to neo4j database management system it throws below error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/connect_to_code] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.TransientException: There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database.] with root cause
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.TransientException: There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database.
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:457)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:418)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:176)
```

I have changed the neo4j.conf file with below parameter:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size = 1024G
dbms.memory.heap.max_size= 1024G
```

Still facing same issue.

Is there anything we can do to avoid this error?

I am not sure where this heap is allocated but my drive free size is as below:
C drive : 26.6 GB D drive : 67.6 GB
RAM :32 GB

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration says  1024G  you may want to change that to 1024M not G.   Try increasing the heap settings if you still get the error after you fix the typo.